# GAD adLoader Delegates not get Called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, admob

Im trying to implement native ads but the adLoader Delegates don't get called. The more interesting is that the delegate for some reason becomes prints nil. No errors printed not receive. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
func getAd(){
let adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: adUnitID, rootViewController: self, adTypes: [.native], options: [options])
    adLoader.delegate = self
    print(adLoader.delegate)
    adLoader.load(GADRequest())
}
extension ViewController:GADNativeAdDelegate, GADAdLoaderDelegate{
func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didReceive nativeAd: GADNativeAd) {
    print("did receive")
  // A native ad has loaded, and can be displayed.
}

func adLoaderDidFinishLoading(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader) {
    print("finish Loading")
    // The adLoader has finished loading ads, and a new request can be sent.
}


func adLoader(_ adLoader: GADAdLoader, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
  print(error)
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare delegate and create an object?

Comment: @RajaKishan adLoader is in a custom function.. just updated the coded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem.. For anyone in the future who has the same issue, the correct delegate is GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate and not GADNativeAdDelegate nor GADAdLoaderDelegate

Answer (score 4):

Currently, your `GADAdLoader` object scope is within the `getAd` function. Once the function is over all things release.

Try to set `GADAdLoader` object reference within the class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var adLoader: GADAdLoader!
    
    func getAd(){
        self.adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: adUnitID, rootViewController: self, adTypes: [.native], options: [options])
        adLoader.delegate = self
        print(adLoader.delegate)
        adLoader.load(GADRequest())
    }
}
```

Comment: Nop, same issue.. Don't know why this is even though I use effectively GADBannerView in the same controller

Comment: Still, delegate print nil?

Comment: yes.. is there any way outside delegate methods to debug the issue?

Comment: Can you please post your full code? When getAd function call?

Comment: func getAd(){ is called when the cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for specific row. Used to do this with GADBannerView but now i want to make it native for darkMode customization